# Bulk edit using RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am using RailsAdmin and I need to be able to :

- Bulk select multiple models (this is easy)
- Edit some columns for all of them (bulk edit)

So I have to select multiple items and go to a custom page where I am editing values for multiple models at the same time.

Any ideas?